# Encrypting large files with Pycrypto by streaming the file rather than one big string

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm encrypting/decrypting files of all sizes and kinds, from small text files to video files of a few GB. The Pycrypto classes just have encode(string) as the only encoding method, implying I must pass the whole file as one big string (a Python 2.7 bytes/string, that is). This seems less than ideal. How can I feed Pycrypto blocks piecemeal? If I were to split the file into chunks (each a fixed number of blocks in size) and encrypt those chunks individually with the same key, would doing so thwart Cipher Block Chaining? (btw, I'm using AES with 256-bit keys and a unique iv for each file.)

EDIT: answered own question below, but that raises another: what is a good chunk size to use? One block at a time or several at once? And anyone know of a convenient method that reads a file but pads it to a multiple of the block size?

Comment: I think the [m2crypto](http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/m2/) module may have better support for block ciphers.

Comment: You should be still be able to use CBC while sending chunks of the ciphertext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, duh, quick experiment:

```
>>> obj = AES.new('blablablablablab', AES.MODE_CBC, 'a' * 16)
>>> obj.encrypt('z' * 16)
"?R\xd9/\xc2\xcb\x98\x8cL\xd4\xe3M\r'-k"
>>> obj.encrypt('z' * 16)
'\xa0QL\x92\xcb\xac{y\xceG\xce\xe2\x05t\xe8\xc3'
>>> obj.encrypt('z' * 16)
'\xc4x\x87L\x025\xbc\xe6\xf1`\x16w\xe0\x94$\x17'
>>>
```

Same input, different results. So each cipher object you create must retain IV state: each call to encode with the same cipher object is for the next chunk of your message.

Answer (score 0):

```
4096
```

It is just the memory block size I've seen used most often. I'd probably go with that.